# Having problems with yaml.cpp lib in c++

Tags: visual-c++, linker, yaml-cpp

I am having a hard time trying to use  yaml-cpp 0.3.0 on my project
I downloaded yaml, and built it like http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/ said, with VS 9 2008 WIN 64. So, i got the yaml-cpp.dll and the yaml-cpp.lib
I have a c++ project on VS 2010 express, and i am trying to link the library: 
I go to project properties - c/c++ general and additional include directories that have yaml-cpp header files. Then i go to linker and add path to my lib directory, then I go to linker - input and add my .lib file, then i go to VC++ Directories and add path to my lib directory in Library directories and Reference directories
Then i try to build this simple code:

```
std::ifstream fin("test.yaml");
YAML::Parser parser(fin);
YAML::Node doc;
while(parser.GetNextDocument(doc)) {
    //do nothing yet
}
```

I got several linking problems, like this:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall YAML::Node::Node(void)" (??0Node@YAML@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Parser::Parser(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Parser@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)


error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall YAML::Parser::~Parser(void)" (??1Parser@YAML@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Parser::Parser(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??0Parser@@QAE@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

Can anyone help me? I am banging my head against a wall here.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you've got a DLL from YAML, I assume you specified `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` when you built with VS2008, so you ended up with a `lib` for dynamic linking (to the DLL at runtime) rather than static linking (at compile time).

If the above is correct, it may be differences between VS2008 and VS2010 that are causing a problem. For example, [see this post here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/ac03e00d-d26a-4d92-9b9f-91ed4b20cfbe). To quickly see if this is the cause, in your VS2010 project properties, set the `Platform Toolset` to `V90` and see if that helps.

Also, make sure you compiled both projects for the same CPU - i.e. both for 32-bit or both for 64-bit.

Comment: Yes, i used -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON. I tried to change the Platform Toolset and it didn't fixed it. Anyway, i had tryed to add the library to a VS2008 project and i got the same errors, so i don't think that's the problem

Comment: Besides, i also had tryed to use -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF and got the same errors